# I can*t run Spring Boot application because of "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for AAA.class"

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

On Eclipse, I'm making Spring Boot Web Application.
When I tried to run the app, I couldn't because of the error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for api/repository/MyRepo (class file version 56.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'
```

I checked Eclipse Settings

- Installed JRE -> OpenJDK12
- Complier level -> Java12, and preview is disabled

and I checked the class version

```
mydir$ javap -v MyRepo.class | grep "major version"
  major version: 56
mydir$
```

It's saying compiled by Java12.

- Spring Boot 2.1.9
- Gradle 5.1.2

Comment: The error message makes it sound like that's a setting you need to turn on. Java 12 has been obsoleted, though, and you should either be in Java 14 at this time or back on Java 11 (the latest LTS release).

Comment: Post `BilledReissueRequestRepository.java` file